# DataGridView Mayúsculas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un DataGridView que le ingreso directamente datos pero quiero que al momento de escribir en la celda se escriba en mayúsculas.
¿Que es lo que debo de hacer?

Comment: para todas las celdas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder escribir en mayuscula debes asociar el evento KeyPress en la celda cuando esta entra en edicion.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl text = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
    text.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(textbox_KeyPress);
    text.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textbox_KeyPress);
}


private void textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.KeyChar = char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Esto aplica a todas las celdas, si necesitas algunas especificas deberias validarlo en el `EditingControlShowing`

Comment: Me sale este error donde se crea los métodos: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler' en 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler', no uso formularios uso UserControl.

Comment: edite el codigo analiza si ahora funciona

Comment: Estoy usando el DGV del DevComponents como le digo que el control es del de Devcomponents: DataGridViewTextBoxDropDownEditingControl text = (DataGridViewTextBoxDropDownEditingControl)e.((DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls) (Control));

Comment: Este es el error que me sale: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl' al tipo 'DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.DataGridViewTextBoxDropDownEditingControl'.

Comment: No era necesario decirle que estaba trabajando con un DGV de otra librería.